# how to implement sobo functionality using legacy authentication in docusign-esign-java client

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign-esign-java client SDK for 'docusign' integrations. I need to implement sobo functionality after I have logged into docusign using legacy authentication API of docusign. How I can achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. Please accept ("check") the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

To activate SOBO (Send On Behalf Of), you just need to add `<SendOnBehalfOf>bob.smith@gmail.com</SendOnBehalfOf>` to your existing `X-DocuSign-Authentication` HTTPS header with your call.

Example:

```
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><SendOnBehalfOf>bob.smith@gmail.com</SendOnBehalfOf><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

[Docs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#SOBO/Send%20On%20Behalf%20Of%20Functionality%20in%20the%20DocuSign%20REST%20API.htm) (We're working on adding this info to the new docs too.)

Comment: yes I can achieve this but I need to apply SOBO after I logged into docusign account. Do I need to add it in header and again log in?

Comment: The Signature REST API does not use sessions, so the so-called "login" call is not actually logging you in. You can add the sobo section to any call that you make to DocuSIgn (except for some calls where SOBO is not supported), and the SOBO will be in effect for just that call. Thank you for using DocuSign.